# Error "Memory Limit" (an infinite loop, c#)

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code. A compiler shows error "MemoryLimit". I suppose, this error because of an Infinite loop.

In my opinion, an operator "if else" in "DoSmth" causes this error, but I have no idea how correct it. I tried few options of this method, but nothing happened.

Could you help me with my code and correct it? Thank you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TableParser
{
    public class FieldsParserTask
    {
        public static readonly char[] FieldSeparators =
        {
            '\"', '\'', ' '
        };

        public static void DoSmth(List<string> fields, string line, int count, bool Method)
        {
            if (Method)
            {
                fields.Add(FindField(line, count).Value);
                count = FindField(line, count).GetIndexNextToToken();
            }
            else
            {
                fields.Add(ReadField(line, count).Value);
                count = ReadField(line, count).GetIndexNextToToken();
            }
        }

        public static List<string> ParseLine(string line)
        {
            var fields = new List<string>();
            var count = 0;
            while (count < line.Length)
            {
                if (line[count] == ' ')
                    count++;
                else if (!FieldSeparators.Contains(line[count]))
                {
                    DoSmth(fields,line,count,true);
                }
                else
                {
                    DoSmth(fields,line,count,false);
                }
            }
            return fields;
        }

        public static Token FindField(string line, int count)
        {
            int length = count;
            while (length < line.Length && !FieldSeparators.Contains(line[length]))
                length++;
            string value = line.Substring(count, length - count);
            return new Token(value, count, length - count);
        }

        public static Token ReadField(string line, int count)
        {
            var value = "";
            char symbol = line[count];
            var countNow = count + 1;
            while (countNow < line.Length && line[countNow] != symbol)
            {
                if (line[countNow] == '\\')
                    countNow++;
                value += line[countNow];
                countNow++;
            }
            return new Token(value, count, countNow - count + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you want to pass `ref int count` (instead of `int count`)  to `DoSmth` (or make `DoSmth` return an `int`)

Comment: The compiler shows a "memory limit" error? I think you confuse something. Are you really talking about the compiler (which is a tool that just translates your C# source code into CLR byte code but does not execute/run your program)? Or are you rather talking about a problem that occurs when your program **is running**? (Note that the compiler is not involved at all in running your program...)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a description of the desired behavior of the code. Here is a link to the guidelines on asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an infinite loop in your ParseLine line method. You only increment the value of count if the the character is a space. You should be aware that `int` is a value type so when you pass count to one of the other methods, you're actually passing a copy of its value, so any changes won't affect the value of the original variable.

Here is a link to Microsoft's documentation about value types.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types

You could update the value of your count variable by replacing

```
var count = 0;
while (count < line.Length)
{
    if (line[count] == ' ')
        count++;
    else if (!FieldSeparators.Contains(line[count]))
    {
         DoSmth(fields,line,count,true);
    }
    else
    {
         DoSmth(fields,line,count,false);
    }
}
```

with

```
var count = 0;
while (count < line.Length)
{
    if (line[count] == ' ')
        count++;
    else if (!FieldSeparators.Contains(line[count]))
    {
         count = DoSmth(fields,line,count,true).Count;
    }
    else
    {
         count = DoSmth(fields,line,count,false).Count;
    }
}
```